# Rviz for 3 robot

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a beginner in using ROS.  I want to ask is it possible to run rviz for 3 kobuki robot in a laptop?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156121/rviz-for-3-robot/) by [girl](https://answers.ros.org/users/15086/girl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-04-22**:
can you explain more about your problem such as what do you want to see in rviz ? do you have problem in network between three robot or something else ....

**Comment by [girl](https://answers.ros.org/users/15086/girl/) on 2014-04-23**:
I am thinking, can I run rviz for 3 robot in one laptop? Is it possible? I haven't test it yet..
Is there anyone that have try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes rviz can display 3 robots simultaneously as long as you make sure they don't share the same link names and have network connectivity. Note: rviz is only a visualization tool.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1